# Last executed queries on SQL Azure Database (Basic tier)

Tags: sql-server, azure

I want to execute this:

`SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC`

on a **SQL Azure Database (basic tier)**, but I'm getting:

`Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
VIEW DATABASE STATE permission denied in database 'master'.
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The user does not have permission to perform this action.`

The only login for the server I have is the same that the one for the database itself... so how do I access the master db?

What are the steps to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access DMV queries on Azure SQL, you need to set-up the permissions on your database.

```
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO database_user;
```

[More about DMV you can read here](https://azure.microsoft.com/cs-cz/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/).

Comment: So... I login with Management Studio to my database with my only db user and then I run that query? its weird to grant permission to myself isn't it?

Comment: Didn't work. I got this: "Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself."

Answer (score 0):

If I run that query on Management Studio, it returns error. But, If I run that query on Azure Query Editor, it works.